# My background image doesn't want to appear !?

Tags: html, css, web

I have an HTML file with a subdirectory called **images** with an image called home-back.jpg. In my CSS file, I have:

[image]

My html:

[image]

The background image is not getting displayed, I am only seeing a white background. Any ideas how to fix this please?

Comment: Please post your code as text next time. Also you need to reference your css file in the html.

Comment: @Berrick.  It could be a path issue from css style sheet to your image folder.  Check your development tools, and make sure you are not getting a 404 error on that image.  In chrome, right click the screen and hit inspect and then click the console tab.

Comment: It says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: @Berrick.  This is a path issue.  You need to correct the (../path/to/images) part.

Comment: @Berrick I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you haven't linked your `style.css` file.
add:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

and also, you haven't set any width for  `#home`.

Comment: I linked my style.css to my html file but it still doesn't want to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the link for the CSS ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Ahahaha ! well seen !

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't get why people make separate css files, unless they are large and there is a mass quantity of them.

put the css in your code by doing

```
<style>
All your css in here
</style>
```

This `<style>` tag goes in the `<head>` tag

Also, make sure to complete the styling for everything.

But if you're gonna link it, use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` in the `<head>` tag.

I realized you are having trouble. If you don't plan to put any child for the image, you can make it a `<img>` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

A part of the answer is already given by Nicat and Paul. You also missed a `;` after the height.

Are both the index.html as styles.css in the same (root) directory? Then you need to change the path to `background-image: url('images/home-back.jpg')`.

I would suggest writing your css as follows:

```
#home {
   background-image: url('../images/home-back.jpg');
   height: 700px;
}
```

This makes your code easier to read and prevents for the small bugs.

Answer (score 0):

@Berrick Check your url('../path/to/images')

The Directory to your image files needs to be relative to your CSS Style sheet and your CSS Style Sheet needs to relative to your Index.html.

Comment: Did you try /images/home-back.jpg?  In Chrome hit CTRL-F5 after changing.

Comment: Yes I did. Not sure why this is still happening.

Comment: Check to see if any CSS is working.  Remove that line and add something else like, `body { background: black;}` to make sure your CSS is being found by the HTML